# Kotlin sealed class subclass needs to be casted to base class if provided as RxJava Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I'm trying to avoid terminal states of RxJava chains in my app written in Kotlin, so I found out that it is right thing to transform `Observable<T>` to `Observable<Result<T>>` where `Result` is sealed class.

```java
sealed class Result<T>
data class Success<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
data class Failure<T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Result<T>()
```

And let's say I have this network request observable.

```java
fun getOrganization(): Observable<Result<Boolean>> {
    return api.getOrganization("google")
            .map { Success(true) }
            .onErrorReturn { Failure(RuntimeException("throwable")) }
}
```

So what I want to do in the end is to handle result like this.

```java
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    getOrganization().subscribe({
        when (it) {
            is Success -> print("success = ${it.data}")
            is Failure -> print("failure = ${it.throwable}")
        }
    })
}
```

Everything should work great, but I have this error in IDE.

[image: error]

Isn't it just simple using of subclass instead of base class?

I found out that if I explicitly cast `Success(true)` to `Result<Boolean>` everything works, but shows this warning.

[image: warning]

Why it even happens and what am I doing wrong here?

**UPD.**
It looks like the main issue here is near rxjava's onErrorReturn operator. If I remove it completely, then it works even without `out` keyword like answers suggest.

[image: without onErrorReturn]

If I return `Success` from both map and onErrorReturn then `out` keyword helps to get rid of errors.

But if I return `Failure` from onErrorReturn there's still error. Compiler has to know that `Failure` `Result` typed with the same `Boolean` as `Success`. What should I do to avoid it or to satisfy it's requirements?

[image: with failure]

Comment: Have you tried to set return type to Observable<out Result<Boolean>? Or you can try to use cast() operator of RxJava

Answer (score 11, accepted):

maybe you misunderstand the generic variance in kotlin. it works fine since  `Success<Boolean>` is a subtype of `Result<Boolean>`. so the "**No need cast**" warning reported and the code below works fine:

```
val ok:Success<Boolean>  = Success(true);
val result:Result<Boolean>  = ok;
```

**But** you can't assign a `Success<Boolean>` to a `Result<Any>` since their type parameters are different, so this why compiler reports the  "**Type mismatch**" error , for example:

```
val ok:Success<Boolean>  = Success(true);
val result1:Result<Any>  = ok;// error
val result2:Result<out Any>  = ok;// ok
```

to fix the error and warnings you can try the code below:

```
fun getOrganization(): Observable<out Result<Boolean>> {
    return api.getOrganization("google")
            .map<Result<Boolean>> { Success(true) }
            .onErrorReturn { Failure(RuntimeException("throwable")) }
}
```

for more details, you can see [java generic subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) & [kotlin type projections](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections).

[image: java generic subtype]

Comment: This totally makes sense now, but there is still something wrong with Failure. I've updated my question with new details.

Comment: @P_King just makes map return a `Result<Boolean>`   as `map<Result<Boolean>>{...}`.

Answer (score 7):

An `Observable<Success<Boolean>>` is not a subtype `Observable<Result<Boolean>>`, just as `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`. See the [Generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance) documentation.

To solve this, either return an `Observable<out Result<Boolean>>`, or explicitly add a type to your `map` function:

```
.map<Result<Boolean>> { Success(true) }
```